# How can I extract information from the string returned in Period.between()? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, date, split, period

For example, I'd have two dates as expected in the function.

```
val period = Period.between(date1, date2)
```

What is returned is a `String` like this `"P*y*Y*x*M*z*D"` where `y` is the year, `x` is the month and `z` is the day. I want to store each of these values in separate variables.

At first I tried using `.split()` but I couldn't find a way to account for all the letters.

It's worth mentioning as well that if the period between the two dates is less than a year for example, the returned string would be `"P*x*M*z*D"`. Same goes for the month as well. So how can I extract this information while accounting for all the possible formats of the returned `String`?

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the string? How about just use the `Period` as a `Period`?

Comment: _"What is returned is a string"_ - no! What is returned is a [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html).

Comment: Don't confuse the `toString()` representation of the `Period` with the `Period` object itself. And if for some reason you start out with only a string in the described format, don't try to parse it yourself; just use [`Period#parse(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) and get the values you need from the returned `Period` object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Period` has fields that can be accessed:

```
fun main() {
    val date1 = LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 3)
    val date2 = LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 5)
    val period = Period.between(date1, date2)
    println("years: ${period.years}, months: ${period.months}, days: ${period.days}")
}
```

Output:

```
years: 0, months: 2, days: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`Period` class has method `get` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) which can give you desired information:

```kotlin
val period = Period.between(date1, date2)
val years = period.get(ChronoUnit.YEARS)
val months = period.get(ChronoUnit.MONTHS)
val days = period.get(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
```